# 9650SE-4LPML RAID Controller BIOs not showing HDDs

Tags: raid, bios, controller

I've got a fresh server put together with a 9650SE-4LPML controller card in it with the intention of setting up RAID 1 with two 2TB HDDS. When I boot up and go into the RAID controller BIOs, the drives aren't seen. I've switched out the controller, switched cables, double checked everything physical and I can't figure out why the HDDS won't show up. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

flash the 3ware card with latest firmware & bios if you haven't.

it's [here](http://www.lsi.com/support/pages/download-results.aspx?component=Storage%20Component&productfamily=Legacy%20RAID%20Controllers&productcode=P00080&assettype=Firmware&productname=3ware%209650SE-4LPML)